# what do i write so it if the user inputs an x it stops

Tags: python

Write a script that continuously accepts numeric inputs from the user.  It does not have to accept decimals.  When the user submits an “x” the program stops asking for user input.  Upon the user typing an “x”, the script will tell the user how many numbers have been entered and the total sum of the values.

Comment: Write a loop that reads an input. It checks if it's 'x', if so it breaks out of the loop. If not, it converts it to a number and adds it to the total variable. After the loop it prints the total.

Comment: Hello on Stack Overflow. Have you tried to find a solution by your own? Please also read this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 1):

Use a while loop that appends each casted input to a list, then use sum() and len() to find the total sum and array length.